# Using gst-launch to streaming video?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to stream a media file (video or audio). I used command:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="/home/ms/GStreamerTest/test.ogg" ! vorbisenc \
! rtpvorbispay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

to stream the file `test.ogg`, but, I got an error:

```
"ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVorbisEnc:vorbisenc0: Internal GStreamer error: negotiation problem.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstvorbisenc.c(1227): gst_vorbis_enc_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVorbisEnc:vorbisenc0:
encoder not initialized (input is not audio?)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

Please help me solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You plugged an encoded and muxed bitstream into an audio encoder. That cannot possibly work.

In your case `filesrc ! udpsink` would send your file across the network and on the other side you have to receive it `udpsrc`, demux it `oggdemux`, decode it `theoradec` or `vorbisdec`, and pipe it into a sink `autovideosink` or `autoaudiosink`

Comment: yeah, when i remove encoder, this command same as: "gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="/home/motsach/GStreamerTest/test.ogg" ! rtpvorbispay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000". But, this doesn't work, i have gotten errors: "Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVorbisPay:rtpvorbispay0: Could not decode stream. ...
Ignoring unknown header received
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVorbisPay:rtpvorbispay0: Element doesn't implement handling of this stream. Please file a bug." Please explain for me, thanks!